# Find what project in TFS that is taking up space

Tags: tfs

We need to figure out what project is making our TFS database to grow out of hand and we [found this script](https://naveenalm.wordpress.com/2015/08/04/dar/) but it does not work with the latest version of TFS.

Does anyone have any updated script for this?

Comment: You can find a lot of useful scripts in this post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63712/tfs-database-size.html

Answer (score 3):

First you could run a SQL script to show an increase of the `tbl_Content` over the last several months:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, CreationDate) AS [year]
    ,DATEPART(mm, CreationDate) AS [month]
    ,COUNT(*) AS [count]
    ,SUM(DATALENGTH(Content)) / 1048576.0 AS [Size in Mb]
    ,(SUM(DATALENGTH(Content)) / 1048576.0) / count(*) AS [Average Size]
FROM tbl_Content
GROUP BY DATEPART(yyyy, CreationDate)
    ,DATEPART(mm, CreationDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(yyyy, CreationDate)
    ,DATEPART(mm, CreationDate)
```

This will reflect if your  collection database have a abnormal increase.  Then you could look at  look at the distribution of "owners" for the data in `tbl_Content` such as VersionControl, Work Item, Test... Which area has the biggest percentage.

Detail SQL script:

```
SELECT Owner = CASE
    WHEN OwnerId = 0 THEN 'Generic'
    WHEN OwnerId = 1 THEN 'VersionControl'
    WHEN OwnerId = 2 THEN 'WorkItemTracking'
    WHEN OwnerId = 3 THEN 'TeamBuild'
    WHEN OwnerId = 4 THEN 'TeamTest'
    WHEN OwnerId = 5 THEN 'Servicing'
    WHEN OwnerId = 6 THEN 'UnitTest'
    WHEN OwnerId = 7 THEN 'WebAccess'
    WHEN OwnerId = 8 THEN 'ProcessTemplate'
    WHEN OwnerId = 9 THEN 'StrongBox'
    WHEN OwnerId = 10 THEN 'FileContainer'
    WHEN OwnerId = 11 THEN 'CodeSense'
    WHEN OwnerId = 12 THEN 'Profile'
    WHEN OwnerId = 13 THEN 'Aad'
    WHEN OwnerId = 14 THEN 'Gallery'
    WHEN OwnerId = 15 THEN 'BlobStore'
    WHEN OwnerId = 255 THEN 'PendingDeletion'
    END,
    SUM(CompressedLength) / 1024.0 / 1024.0 AS BlobSizeInMB
FROM tbl_FileReference AS r
JOIN tbl_FileMetadata AS m ON r.ResourceId = m.ResourceId
    AND r.PartitionId = m.PartitionId
WHERE r.PartitionId = 1
GROUP BY OwnerId
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

(For more information, please refer the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63712/tfs-database-size.html) @jessehouwing provided in the comment.)

To reduce the size of the tbl_Content table, you could refer to this blog: [TFS tbl_Content Table and Database growth out of control](https://mattyrowan.com/2014/04/02/need-help-tfs-tbl_content-table-and-database-growth-out-of-control/)

1. Clean some old workspaces that you doesn't need any more.
2. Run the [tf destory command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control) to delete those unnecessary source files permanently.
3. Using TFS power tool to [clean Test attachments](https://tatvog.wordpress.com/2015/11/06/116/) and test results.

Comment: Maybe add a warning about the script above taking quite some time, so running it on a large production instance should be done while extra load would be okay.