# Is there way to increase database size limit in tfs 2013 my collection is full?

Tags: sql, tfs

Is there way to increase database size limit in tfs 2013 my collection is full
i upgrade instance by sql server 2012 but still my conllection full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please double check the disk space of your SQL Server. If the dive is full then you could take below options:

- Option 1: Clean the drive to free up space. Delete transaction logs,
  look for extraneous test case attachments, build drops checked into
  source that sort of thing.
- Option 2: Get a bigger hard drive.

More details about how to find  which project is taking up space and 
  [Find what project in TFS that is taking up space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012699/find-what-project-in-tfs-that-is-taking-up-space/47030328#47030328)

If the issue is not related to disk space ,you could also try to open the properties of the TFS_DefaultCollection database and changed the autogrowth property to **Unrestricted File Growth**.

[image]

More detail info please take a look at this [blog](https://roadtoalm.com/2011/09/05/solving-tf30042-the-database-is-full-contact-your-team-foundation-server-administrator/).

Comment: Thanks for quick response i don't have any issues in disk space and database file is already unlimited

Comment: @AhmedSami What's the detail error do you got? Also check the Event View on TFS sever if there are some useful information for troubleshooting. You could update related  info in your original question.

Comment: TF30042: The database is full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

Comment: @AhmedSami Are you using  Express SQL version? Besides also try to run the install of your sql server and select  Maintenance and click  Edition upgrade. Another way is checking if SQL TempDB log file was full. Take a look at this similar issue https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4558bcb9-752c-4a17-a5bd-d1bff71da018/tf30042-the-database-is-full-contact-your-team-foundation-server-administrator?forum=tfsadmin